# String#pack works on 1.9+, not 1.8*

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, pack, ruby-1.8

I stumbled upon an error that I don't quite understand.

```
# Ruby 1.8.7
>> [Digest::MD5.hexdigest("http://www.google.com").to_i(16)].pack("N")
RangeError: bignum too big to convert into 'unsigned long'

# Ruby 1.9.3
>> [Digest::MD5.hexdigest("http://www.google.com").to_i(16)].pack("N")
=> "17!@"
```

Anybody can explain why, and how can I solve this? If no portable solution can be used, I need one for 1.8.7.

Comment: What do you want with that .pack('N')? Shorten the result?

Comment: Yes, I am using a snippet of code from https://github.com/technoweenie/guillotine/blob/master/lib/guillotine.rb

Comment: Then go with Said's suggestion. ("N") will only take the last 32 bit so modulo won't change the outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **Ruby 1.8+**, pack fails if the value is too large - but you can get the same behaviour by only considering the low order bits, by changing:

```
[Digest::MD5.hexdigest("http://www.google.com").to_i(16)].pack("N")
```

to

```
[Digest::MD5.hexdigest("http://www.google.com").to_i(16) % 2**32].pack("N")
```